# Assembly NASM x86 - Simple Stack Project

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm writing a subroutine to simply reprint decimal numbers as strings using the stack, but not getting the values I expected. When I run it through the debugger I see that I can't get the value from esi into al. I suspect that I'm not allowed to use esi in the manner that I am, but I'm not sure on another way I can do this. Also, I am not allowed to push the elements I'm storing in edx onto the stack.

Subroutine code:

```
%define STDIN 0
%define STDOUT 1
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  1
%define SYSCALL_READ  3
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 4
%define BUFLEN 256

        SECTION .bss                    ; uninitialized data section
src_str: resb BUFLEN            ; buffer for backwards number
dec_str: resb BUFLEN                    ; number will be converted and put in this buffer
rlen:    resb 4             ; length

    SECTION .text           ; code begins here
    global      prt_dec

    ; Begin subroutine

prt_dec:
    push    eax
    push    ebx         
    push    ecx
    push    edx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    mov     eax, [esp + 28]     ; store the decimal number 4 bytes each for each push, plus the eip
    mov esi, src_str        ; point esi to the backwards string buffer
    mov     edi, dec_str        ; point edi to the new buffer   
        mov     ebx, 10         ; stores the constant 10 in ebx

div_loop:
    mov edx, 0          ; clear out edx
    div     ebx         ; divide the number by 10
    add     edx, '0'                ; convert from decimal to char
    mov [esi], edx      ; store char in output buffer
    inc     esi         ; move to next spot in output buffer
    inc     ecx         ; keep track of how many chars are added
    cmp eax, 0          ; is there anything left to divide into?
    jne     div_loop        ; if so, continue the loop

output_loop:
    add esi, ecx        ; move 1 element beyond the end of the buffer
    mov al, [esi - 1]       ; move the last element in the buffer into al           
    mov [edi], al       ; move it into the first position of the converted output buffer
    inc edi         ; move to the next position of the converted output buffer
    dec ecx         ; decrement to move backwards through the output buffer
    cmp ecx, 0          ; if it doesn't equal 0, continue loop 
    jne output_loop 

print:  
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write out string
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, dec_str
    mov     edx, 0                
        mov     edx, rlen           
        int     080h

pop_end:
    pop     edi         ; move the saved values back into their original registers
    pop     esi
    pop edx         
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop     eax
    ret

    ; End subroutine
```

Driver:

```
%define STDIN 0
%define STDOUT 1
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  1
%define SYSCALL_READ  3
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 4


        SECTION .data                   ; initialized data section

lf:     db  10                  ; just a linefeed 

msg1:   db " plus " 
len1 equ $ - msg1

msg2:   db " minus "
len2 equ $ - msg2

msg3:   db " equals "
len3 equ $ - msg3

        SECTION .text                   ; Code section.
        global  _start                  ; let loader see entry point
    extern  prt_dec

_start: 
    mov ebx, 17
    mov edx, 214123
    mov edi, 2223187809
    mov ebp, 1555544444 


    push    dword 24
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    dword 0xFFFFFFFF
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    3413151
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    ebx
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    edx
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    edi
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    ebp
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    2
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg1
        mov     edx, len1
        int     080h

    push    3
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg3
        mov     edx, len3
        int     080h

    push    5
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf

    push    7
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg2
        mov     edx, len2
        int     080h

    push    4
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg3
        mov     edx, len3
        int     080h

    push    3
    call    prt_dec
    add esp, 4
    call    prt_lf


        ; final exit
        ;
exit:   mov     EAX, SYSCALL_EXIT       ; exit function
        mov     EBX, 0                  ; exit code, 0=normal
        int     080h                    ; ask kernel to take over



    ; A subroutine to print a LF, all registers are preserved
prt_lf:
    push    eax
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    push    edx

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, lf
        mov     edx, 1          ; LF is a single character
        int     080h

    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    ret
```

Comment: When running it in the debugger what does it show you as you step through the instructions and look at the registers and memory?

Comment: *"I see that for whatever reason I can't get the value from esi into al."* - there's never "whatever" reason, CPU is deterministic state machine. If you fetch byte B from address A, then at address A **is** byte B (as you can verify in memory view). So in your case expecting digit character, either it was wrongly written into `src_str` buffer and the memory doesn't contain it, or you are fetching from wrong address. Try it again in debugger. (the bugfix needs just few changes to `output_loop`. And then the `print:` has one bug too.)

Comment: And one advanced hint (not related to any of those bugs), `inc` and `dec` does affect zero flag on x86, so in output_loop `dec ecx` `jnz output_loop` is enough, that `cmp ecx,0` is not needed.

Comment: It always shows that 0 is stored in al, and I set it to display al right after I begin running it. al never changes. Everything else is correct. The decimal value stored in edx is correct, and eax changes appropriately, ecx increments properly as items are added.

Comment: you can't follow only B ... follow also A. (ie `esi` values) .. follow them already trough the build of string, so you know where it lands, and compare that with `src_str` address, whether that makes sense. Then you will know where each digit is stored, and what is expected address to read it back. Also when writing digits `mov [esi],edx` stores DWORD, while ASCII is BYTE, so it's sort of bug (but doesn't affect result). (BTW, I'm running it + debugging in head only.. and I haven't code anything in ASM for ~15 years, just following logic and being accurate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes I had on mind (asterisk denotes lines I did touch), hopefully it will be clear from comments what I did:

```
    ...
div_loop:
*   xor     edx, edx    ; clear out edx
    div     ebx         ; divide the number by 10
*   add     dl, '0'     ; convert from decimal to char
*   mov     [esi], dl   ; store char in output buffer
    inc     esi         ; move to next spot in output buffer
    inc     ecx         ; keep track of how many chars are added
*   test    eax,eax     ; is there anything left to divide into?
*   jnz     div_loop    ; if so, continue the loop
* ; (jnz is same instruction as jne, but in this context I like "zero" more)

*   mov     [rlen], ecx ; store number of characters into variable

output_loop:
* ; esi already points beyond last digit, as product of div_loop (removed add)
*   dec     esi         ; point to last/previous digit
    mov     al, [esi]   ; move the char from the div_loop buffer into al
    mov     [edi], al   ; move it into the first position of the converted output buffer
    inc     edi         ; move to the next position of the converted output buffer
    dec     ecx         ; decrement to move backwards through the output buffer
*   jnz     output_loop ; if it doesn't equal 0, continue loop 

print:  
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write out string
    mov     ebx, STDOUT
    mov     ecx, dec_str
*   mov     edx, [rlen] ; read the number of digits from variable
    int     080h

    ...
```

Comment: Interesting...I think the big problem was using dl instead of edx when moving it into esi. Is that because its size is read appropriately as a byte instead of a word? If not, do you know why? I made some of these changes and the majority of output is correct but it segfaults once it gets to 2 plus 3, but I'll churn through dbg some more to figure out why.

Comment: @swingonaspiral: your `mov [esi],edx` to store digit should work OK too, just overwriting a bit of the next buffer which doesn't matter, because you overwrite it then with reversed string anyway. That output_loop of yours was mostly failing because of `add esi,ecx` .. that would be correct only with `mov esi,src_str` ahead of that `add` in every loop cycle. Which is not needed, as the `esi` already points beyond the last digit from the writing. Really, if you will step through it slowly and watch registers + memory window set on buffers, it should explain it better than me.

Comment: about segfault: I took a quick look, and I have no idea, didn't spot any bug in "driver" part. Try to get exact instruction of crash in debugger and then figure out why it does crash. That's usually the easier part. Then figure out how that code went into such state, and what it was supposed to do in correct version and where is the source of the problem.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I'm really super new to assembly to state the obvious, and I was poring over the debugger following every single register and in fact had tried multiple different things with getting the value out of esi before coming here because I was stumped. However, I did figure out the segfault. ECX wasn't being cleared before being used as the incrementer which was causing weird things to happen. I added a line to zero it out at the beginning of the subroutine and that cleared up the segfault. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @swingonaspiral oh, I see, and before " plus " output you had push/pop ecx everywhere, so it managed to keep zero from the start of program and the error didn't show sooner. I probably skipped the init part of prt_dec too fast, as overall your code in question did look quite good (it could have been fixed only by few lines changed), I didn't expect missing xor ecx,ecx. But I could have catch it after your segfault comment. Well, getting rusty... :) (but nowadays I'm used to Java/C++ and unit testing almost everything, plus debuggers are super friendly).